# How can I store java List using hibernate and spring mvc4?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to persist List of Strings and List of Map's.
I am using hibernate4 and spring mvc4.
I am new to both spring and hibernate
Here is my code.

Professional.java (Bean class)

```
 package com.asmapp.model;

import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "professional")
public class Professional {

@Id
@Column(name="proId")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int proId;

@Column(name="proEmail")
private String proEmail;

@Column(name="proName")
private String proName;

@Column(name="proPhone")
private String proPhone;

@Column(name="proPass")
private String proPass;

@Column(name="proSrvcCat")
private String proSrvcCat;

@Column(name="proExp")
private String proExp;//(0202 means 2 month 12 yr)

@Column(name="proDesc", columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String proDesc;

@ElementCollection
private List<Map<String, Time>> proWorkHr;

@Column(name="proAdd", columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String proAdd;

@ElementCollection
private List<String> proPrefLctn;

@Column(name="proExprts", columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String proExprts;

@Column(name="proImg")
private Blob proImg;

@Column(name="creationTS", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", insertable=false, updatable=true)
private Calendar creationTS;

public String getProName() {
    return proName;
}

public void setProName(String proName) {
    this.proName = proName;
}

public int getProId() {
    return proId;
}

public void setProId(int proId) {
    this.proId = proId;
}

public String getProEmail() {
    return proEmail;
}

public void setProEmail(String proEmail) {
    this.proEmail = proEmail;
}

public String getProPhone() {
    return proPhone;
}

public void setProPhone(String proPhone) {
    this.proPhone = proPhone;
}

public String getProPass() {
    return proPass;
}

public void setProPass(String proPass) {
    this.proPass = proPass;
}

public String getProSrvcCat() {
    return proSrvcCat;
}

public void setProSrvcCat(String proSrvcCat) {
    this.proSrvcCat = proSrvcCat;
}

public String getProExp() {
    return proExp;
}

public void setProExp(String proExp) {
    this.proExp = proExp;
}

public String getProDesc() {
    return proDesc;
}

public void setProDesc(String proDesc) {
    this.proDesc = proDesc;
}

public List<Map<String, Time>> getProWorkHr() {
    return proWorkHr;
}

public void setProWorkHr(List<Map<String, Time>> proWorkHr) {
    this.proWorkHr = proWorkHr;
}

public String getProAdd() {
    return proAdd;
}

public void setProAdd(String proAdd) {
    this.proAdd = proAdd;
}

public List<String> getProPrefLctn() {
    return proPrefLctn;
}

public void setProPrefLctn(List<String> proPrefLctn) {
    this.proPrefLctn = proPrefLctn;
}

public String getProExprts() {
    return proExprts;
}

public void setProExprts(String proExprts) {
    this.proExprts = proExprts;
}

public Blob getProImg() {
    return proImg;
}

public void setProImg(Blob proImg) {
    this.proImg = proImg;
}

public Calendar getCreationTS() {
    return creationTS;
}

public void setCreationTS(Calendar creationTS) {
    this.creationTS = creationTS;
 }
}
```

Whenever I try to run the application, It throws Bean Creation  Exception.
But when I change Map to HashMap it, compiles and runs successfully. Please help me to persist these Collection type Object in database.
My database is MySql.

Error log is as follows

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountCntrl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.asmapp.dao.UserDAO com.asmapp.controller.AccountCntrl.userDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: Professional_proWorkHr, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(proWorkHr)]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
```

These are the errors I am getting

Comment: can you attach error log ?

Comment: is proWorkHr is another entity here?

Comment: its a list of map containing string as key and java.sql.Time as value

Comment: do you want to save this into database field?

Comment: there is still the same error

Comment: can you share your table metadata? to compare the field with it.

Comment: need to configure @Column(name="") mapping too for this field

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
@ElementCollection
private List<Map<String, Time>> proWorkHr;

    public List<Map<String, Time>> getProWorkHr() {
        return proWorkHr;
    }

    public void setProWorkHr(List<Map<String, Time>> proWorkHr) {
        this.proWorkHr = proWorkHr;
    }
```

Comment: Did you add @Column annotation before @ElementCollection?

Answer (score 0):

I would model it a bit different.

```
@Embeddable
public class WorkingHour{
    private String day;
    private Time workHour;

    public WorkingHour(){

    }

    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public Time getWorkHour() {
        return workHour;
    }

    public void setWorkHour(Time workHour) {
        this.workHour = workHour;
    }
}
```

and use it in the `Professional` class like below

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "professional_working_hours", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "proId"))
private Set<WorkingHour> courses = new HashSet<WorkingHour>();

public Set<WorkingHour> getCourses() {
    return courses;
}

public void setCourses(Set<WorkingHour> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
}
```

If you still want to go ahead with your model, try something like below should work(am not sure).

```
private List<Map<String, Time>> proWorkHrs = new ArrayList<>(0);

public void setProWorkHrs(List<Map<String, Time>> proWorkHrs) {
    this.proWorkHrs = proWorkHrs;
}
```

And populate the collection like

```
Map<String, Time> proWorkHr = new HashMap<String, Time>();
proWorkHr.put("a", new Time(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
proWorkHr.put("b", new Time(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
```